# Вывести новости пользователя , на которого я подписана

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Пытаюсь вывести новости тех людей, на которых подписан пользователь, но у меня получается каша. Нет, все выводится, но проблема в том, что они выводятся не по `ORDER BY id DESC`.

[image: Вот бд, посмотрите в каком порядке новости:]

Пытаюсь это вывести через `ORDER BY id DESC`, но выходит вот такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю в чем проблема, но я абсолютно не понимаю, как ее решить и почему так происходит. `while` же не должен отдавать сразу два значения в `$query`.

И еще: возможно ли это сделать с использованием одного цикла?

Вот сам код:

```
// Выбираем всех пользователей на которых Мы подписаны.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM follow WHERE sender='$s_id'";
$sql = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if ($row) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // Получаем их.
    $target = $row['target'];
    // Получаем новости, авторы которых пользователи, на которых мы подписаны.
    // Тут и возникает проблемка. $target почему-то сразу забирается во все поля где он
    //есть в shots , а не одно.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM shots WHERE user_id='$target' AND access='1'  ORDER BY id DESC ";
    $query_go = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $row_shot = mysqli_num_rows($query_go);
    if ($row_shot) {
      while($row_shot = mysqli_fetch_array($query_go,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $title = $row_shot['title'];
        $image = $row_shot['image'];
        echo  "
          <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4\">
            <div class=\"shot\" data-id=\"\">
              <div class=\"shot-preview\">
                <a class=\"img\" href=\"shot?id=\">
                  <img src=\"$image\" alt=\"\">
                </a>
                <h5 class=\"title\">
                  <a href=\"shot-gallery.html\">$title</a>
                </h5>
                <a class=\"label\" href=\"page-search.html\">App</a>
              </div>
              <div class=\"shot-detail\">
                <div class=\"shot-info\">
                  <a href=\"\">
                    <img src=\"assets/img/guest3.png\" alt=\"avatar\">
                  </a>
                  <h6>
                    <a href=\"\">$target</a>
                  </h6>
                  <time datetime=\"2016-02-04 22:30\">2 hours ago</time>
                </div>
                <ul class=\"shot-stats\">
                  <li>
                    <i class=\"fa fa-eye\"></i>
                    <span>1</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href=\"shot?id=\">
                      <i class=\"fa fa-comments\"></i>
                      <span>1s</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: У вас берется один человек, на которого есть подписка - выводятся все его новости, потом второй - выводятся его, потом третий - его новости. В результате получается 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3 (по две новости от каждого пользователя). А как надо? Чтобы было по одной последней новости от каждого? Из вопроса не совсем понятно, какого результата хотите добиться.

Comment: Нужно что бы все новости пользователей выводились , начиная с последних. То есть , что бы было не :

News5
News3
News6
News1
News4
News2,

а 
News6
News5
News4 и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вывести новости в отсортированном по id порядке, можно использовать двух-табличный запрос к таблицам follow и shorts. Это кстати, решит и проблему вложенных циклов, так как у вас будет один запрос и одна результирующая таблица. Отталкиваться можно от следующего запроса

```
SELECT
  f.target AS target,
  s.id AS id,
  s.title AS title,
  s.image AS image
FROM
  follow AS f
JOIN
  shots AS s
ON
  s.user_id = f.target
WHERE
  f.sender = '$s_id' AND
  s.access = '1'
GROUP BY
  s.id
ORDER BY
  s.id DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо,спасибо,спасибо!
То что нужно.